# map response from api return undefined data

Tags: angular, dictionary, undefined

I'm trying to map an array to get a specific value from the api response.
When I get the full response, the data is defined.

```js
EmissionByPolluant(url:string):Observable<emissions[]>{
  return this._http.get(url)
  .pipe(map(res =>res.json()));
}

//method 
this._SaveWrorldService.EmissionByPolluant(this.url).toPromise().then(res=>{
      console.log(res);
```

But when I try to map a specific value from the response, I get an array of undefined item.

```js
  this._SaveWrorldService.EmissionByPolluant(this.url).toPromise().then(res=>{
      console.log(res);
      
      let value=res.map(res =>res.Valoare)
      let name=res.map(res=>res.Denumire)
      let date=res.map(res =>res.An)

      console.log(value);
    })
```

Am I doing something wrong?

[image: Untitled.png]

Comment: I should probably provide what data you're getting. I assume you mean `console.log(value);` gives undefined? Perhaps there is no such field as `Valoare`?

Comment: I import that field from emissions.ts : ```export interface emissions{
    Id:number;
    Denumire:string;
    An:number;
    Valoare:number;
}```

Comment: Add your console logs

Comment: I edit my post,first console.log is from full response and the rest is from values and name.

Answer (score 0):

In `map` you try to read uppercased properties (`Valoare`), but on the screenshot property names are lowercased (`valoare`). Try the following

```js
this._SaveWrorldService.EmissionByPolluant(this.url).toPromise().then(res=>{
      console.log(res);
      
      let value=res.map(res =>res.valoare)  //<- changes are here
      let name=res.map(res=>res.denumire)
      let date=res.map(res =>res.an)

      console.log(value);
    })
```

Comment: When i change it i have errors "Property does not exist on type 'emissions'.

Comment: Can say for sure without proper debugging. Can you provide a [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: You are getting that error because that property in fact does not exist in your `emissions` interface. You need to update the `interface` and change the property name to lowercase as well, i.e. `export interface emissions{ id:number; denumire:string; an:number; valoare:number; }`

Comment: The problem is that in asp.net i group data by name in method emissionByPolluant so in first console.log i got a array of another 6 arrays(one for each name)  and i try to map data from  the first one and this is why i have that error and i don't know how to split it so i can have  6 arrays to map data.